# iCloud ios mail contacts

Tags: ios, contacts, icloud

I want to develop an iOS App, which can access my iCloud mail contacts. Can I do that, does Apple allow such coding?  Or are there some private APIs maybe?
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple exposes the [Address Book framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) for this. Specifically, read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABGroupRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007211) how to find a specific group, such as iCloud.